# adding a data source to the gridview dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here i have tried to do bind the gridview as per the selection in the checkboxlist.
I'm getting only blank page when its executed. can any one specify what's the mistake?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String query = "Select Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end from Proj_details where Front_end = 'Android'";
String[] frontend ={ "Android", "Asp", "Asp.net", "C#.net", "J2EE", "Java", "Matlab", "NS2", "PHP", "VB", "VB.net" };
try
{
for (int i = 0; i <= CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
query = query.Insert(query.Length, frontend[i] + "','");
}

con.Open();
query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1);
query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1);
query = query.Insert(query.Length, ")");
SqlDataAdapter sqlada = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sqlada.Fill(ds, "Proj_details");


gv_search_project.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
gv_search_project.DataBind();



}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{

Label1.Text = query.ToString();
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe you got an exception. Your catch code is empty.

Comment: Ya I got this exception... System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at Search.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Students\lavan\firstweb\Search.aspx.cs:line 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going out of the array here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
      query = query.Insert(query.Length, frontend[i] + "','");
}
```

You need to replace:

```
i <= CheckBoxList1.Items.Count
```

With:

```
i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gv_search_project.DataSource = ds.Tables["Proj_details"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building a query by appending additional `Front_end` values, but the base query you are appending to has a where clause like this:

```
where Front_end = 'Android'
```

So (if I read your code correctly) the resulting query is (for instance):

```
Select Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end 
from Proj_details 
where Front_end = 'Android'Android','C#.net','Matlab','VB')
```

To start with the query i simply broken. And secondly I think what you intended was to have an `IN` clause:

```
String query = "Select Proj_id,Proj_name,Front_end,Back_end from Proj_details where Front_end in ('Android','";
```

This, coupled with **Amiram Korach's** note about `<` vs `<=` should make the code work. But it will always include 'Android' (which you initial attempt also did).

Do change you empty catch clause though:

```
catch (Exception ex)               
{               

}
```

If you hadn't been swallowing all exceptions you would probably have found the problems yourself.